# Closed form expression sum-product of binomials

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

Is it possible to find a closed form expression for

$$\sum_{j=1}^a\sum_{i=1}^{b} {i+j-1\choose j} {i+j-1\choose i},$$
where $a \geq 1$, and $b \geq 1$ are integers.

I couldn't apply any type of Vandermonde formula, neither Mathematica provides me a closed form...

Comment: The problem is not correct in this form, because $a$ and $b$ have and upper bound. Furthermore, I think the problem is just a special case of [the multi-binomial theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem#The_multi-binomial_theorem).

Comment: I don't understand your concern. The sum exists as long as $a \geq 1$, and $b \geq 1$. Also, I don't see how this comes from the multibinomial..

Comment: I would not expect a closed form solution unless you specify values for $a$ and $b$ that are especially nice.  Otherwise, it is hard.  For example, I don't think there's even a closed-form solution for $\sum_{k=0}^a \binom{n}{k}$.

Comment: Except that in my case both upper and lower summands are increasing with $j$...

Answer (score 0):

The following equation may help you.

Note that for any $k>0$
$$ {2 k \choose k+1} = \sum_{i=1}^k {k \choose i}{k \choose k+1-i}  = \sum_{i=1}^k {k \choose i}{k \choose i-1}
$$